# Two independent posix timers created by timer_create() and started with same value do not work as expected

Tags: linux, timer

I created two independent timers one after another using timer_create(), and then started the timers using timer_settime() with same value, but the result is unpredictable.

```
...
struct sigevent sev1, sev2;
struct itimerspec its;
timer_t timerid1, timerid2;
...
sev1.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
sev1.sigev_notify_function = hander1;
sev1.sigev_value.sigval_int = 999;

sev2.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
sev2.sigev_notify_function = hander2;
sev2.sigev_value.sigval_int = 99999;

timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev1, &timer_id1);
timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev2, &timer_id2);

its.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
its.it_value.tv_nsev = 0;
its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
its.it_interval.tv_nsev = 0;

timer_settime(timer_id1, 0, &its);
timer_settime(timer_id2, 0, &its);
...
```

I expect that both handler1 and handler2 would excute after 1 seconds with no fixed order, but the fact is sometimes both excute as expected, sometimes only one of the handlers excutes, the excution result is unpredictable...

Comment: This code doesn't check any function return values, it does not initialise `sev1` or `sev2`'s `sigev_notify_attributes` member and it invokes `timer_settime` with only three arguments instead of the required four.  If your program still doesn't work after you've fixed those issues, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and give us a simplified version of your program that demonstrates the failure. Then we can give you a proper answer instead of having to guess at what might be going wrong.